# Список меток react-yandex-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, map

Как можно вынести отдельно список объектов, по которым можно нажать и перейти на определенную метку, рядом с картой и чтобы они так же работали ?? Пример из doc - [click](https://gribnoysup.github.io/react-yandex-maps/#/sandbox/controls/listbox)

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, отдельный список с метками ( + сами метки ), по клику на которые переходи на их координаты - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-yandex-maps-upbvnt?file=/src/App.js